# Render a Observable object property in Angular template

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-observable

I have the following Angular 7 component:

```
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {

  post$: Observable<PostModel>;

  constructor(private postService: PostService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.post$ = postService.getPostById(25);

  }

}
```

On the component template I used the following:

```
<p>Title: {{post$.title}}</p>
```

Title shows empty and I think is because post$ is an Observable.

When using arrays, e.g. `posts$: Observable<PostModel[]>` I pass the observable to the template and it works fine using `ngFor`.

But how should I do it in this case?

**Observable with an Array**

When using an Observable of an array I have the following in the HTML template:

```
<div *ngIf="(posts$ | async)?.length > 0; else loading">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let post of posts$ | async">
    {{post.title}}
  </ng-container>
</div>
<ng-template #loading>
  Loading ...
</ng-template>
```

This allows me to show a loading message while loading.

Comment: Well what's the difference between what you're doing with `users$` (and `posts$`, for that matter) and what you're doing with `post$`? That should give a you a clue. This is covered in the [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial).

Comment: Obviously you should use the [AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe). Note that every `async` you use subscribes to your Observable, so if your Observable comes from the `HttpClient` then a new http request will be made for every new subscribtion (use of `async` in your template).

Comment: @fridoo To prevent a new http request I could use a wrapper, no? Something like: <ng-container *ngIf="post$ | async as post">. No?

Comment: @MiguelMoura yes, that'll work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will have to use the async pipe as:

```
<p>Title: {{(post$ | async).title}}</p>
```

Comment: What if I have a two way binding such as `[(ngModel)]`?